# How to add dynamic dropdown in admin form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminform, magento2.4, drop-downs

Hello I want to add Dynamic dropdown in admin form , I mean to say I want to fetch data from database and show them in dropdown in admin form in Magento 2?  I already try it but I got following issue.

```
<?php

namespace Vendro\AdminTheme\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Vendor\AdminTheme\Module\Model\ColorFactory;


class EditStatusFormBeforeHtml implements ObserverInterface 
{

protected $request;

protected $helper;

protected $_collection;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Vendor\AdminTheme\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
    ColorFactory $collection
)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->_collection = $collection;
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
     $block =  $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
     if($block->getId() == 'new_order_status') {

        
         $form = $block->getForm();
         $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset_color', ['legend' => __('Customize')]);

         
         $status = $this->request->getParam('status');
         
         $fieldset->addField(
             'color',
             'select',
             [
                 'name' => 'color',
                 'label' => __('Color'),
                 'required' => false,
                 'value'   => $this->getAlldata()
             ]
         );
     }
}

public function getAlldata()
{
    $collection=$this->_collection->create()->getCollection();
    $result = [];

    foreach ($collection as $index => $value) {
        $result[] = [$value->getColorLabel() => $value->getColorId()];
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

The error is
[image]

Please help me to fix this

Comment: can you tell which line is 87??

Comment: and did you try printing $result to check if it contains the value?

Comment: return $result;  -- This is the line no 87

Comment: yes i tried it but it give me array of array

Comment: Please add your full code